# SSO in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, claims-based-auth, sso

I'm completely new to the activities like Single Sign On configuration.
I need to implement SSO in my SharePoint Web Application for a one time login using AD credentials.
Somebody please provide any documentation or step by step procedure in this regard. Thanks!

Abraham

Answer (score 1):

Single Sign-On means something else to different people - e.g. one-time authentication and authorization across multiple systems (front or back-end) or simply being able to delegate credentials from the system you are logged-on to other systems while accessing a services or data.

In SharePoint 2010 for Authentication you could either configure Kerberos which actually allows users to automatically authenticate to SharePoint sites once they are logged-in onto their computers - but that is not single sign-on.

Other systems rely on Forms-based authentication (or Claims-based for more complex scenarios)

Or...rely on Secure-Store, if you are only interested in back-end authentication between SharePoint and other systems, e.g. some back-end systems.

Comment: nice post, agreed it really does depend on what your chosen authentication model is. Abraham - if you can please disclose what version of SharePoint has been implemented and what its chosen authenciation model is (Claims / Classic / Forms / Kerberos) then perhaps the community can give you a better idea.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply  and thanks for the response. I'm actually looking for a functionality which allows users to automatically authenticate to SharePoint sites once they are logged-in onto their computers in their domain. Can you pls share more on this. Your help is appreciated. -Abraham

Comment: Kerberos is the way to go (it will even solve classical problems such as opening documents from SharePoint libraries, etc.). Just be aware that even though configuring it with SharePoint is not very complicated, it does require infrastructure support.

Comment: Hi Can you please share any step by step documentation regarding this?

I have same kind of requirement which has to be implemented against my AD credentials. Thanks a lot!

Abraham

Comment: Straight from MSDN http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23176 or http://www.harbar.net/archive/2010/03/31/sharepoint-2010-and-kerberos.aspx

Comment: you don't need to enable kerberos to allo user to automatically authenticate, for that you only claims based authentication and the claims to windwos token service. 

kerberos is to delegate permissions across servers, and you would only need that when you are creating connections within your sharepoint servers and other servers and passing the current user credentials.